# What does jquery.js, foundation.js, and foundation.alert.js do?

Tags: jquery, zurb-foundation

I asked a previous question earlier about flash messages and how to customize them, but I could really use some clarification about what these files are?

```
<script src="js/vendor/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/foundation/foundation.js"></script>
<script src="js/foundation/foundation.alert.js"></script>
```

What are they and why do I need them? Foundation makes it sound as if it was already included.Am I supposed to put code in them, my rails app doesn't have a vendor directory or jquery.js

Comment: http://jquery.com/
http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/javascript.html
http://foundation.zurb.com/

Just... know the tools you are using ;-)

Comment: These are third party libraries. You're not supposed to put code in them, but you might need to download them and make sure they exist at the required locations.

Answer (score 4):

As you probably know [Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/) is a responsive CSS/JavaScript framework for deploying mobile and desktop ready sites quickly. Foundation provides a large CSS rule set that manages the look of your site, but in order to provide the responsive functionality it requires the use of `JavaScript`.

Foundation Javascript was designed to work with jQuery right out of the gate. You simply need to include the following in the `<head>` section of your page.

Additionally you may want to use `Modernizr` as it acts as a shim for HTML5 elements that older browsers may not recognize, and provides detection for mobile devices.

```
<script src="/js/vendor/modernizr.js"></script>
```

The above is NOT REQUIRED by recommended. It is pretty lightweight and really just sits there. The `JQuery` is used for all the heavy lifting Foundation has to do. It is REQUIRED for any of the functionality of Foundation. The look comes from `CSS` but the functionality comes from `JavaScript`

```
<script src="/js/vendor/jquery.js"></script>
```

You just need to have [JQuery](http://jquery.com/) version 1.10 or higher loaded on your page BEFORE the `foundation.js` library. You can use a `CDN` for it such as [this one](https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.0.min.js) to avoid maintaining a copy locally.

Once that is done you simply need to load the `Foundation Javascript Library`. These are all the functions that are used by Foundation. They are seperated as follows for convenience and portability.

You can EITHER load each plugin individually, or include foundation.min.js, which automatically loads the Foundation Core and all Javascript plugins.

If you use this version then you only need to load the single file for full functionality.

```
<script src="/js/foundation.min.js"></script>
```

The following version (non-minified) will load the core functionality only. This is basically the `grid` re-sizing and utility functions.

```
<script src="/js/foundation.js"></script>
```

Just that file is slightly quicker to load and has slightly less overhead then the `minified` version so this option is commonly used when you only need the core functionality.

To extend on the `non-minified` and add the additional functions like the `Topbar`, `Alerts`, `Dropdowns` and so forth you have to load their respective `Javascript` files which add that functionality to the core `Javascript`

```
<script src="/js/foundation.alert.js"></script>
<script src="/js/foundation.dropdown.js"></script>
<script src="/js/foundation.tab.js"></script>
```

With my deployments I typically setup `JQuery` and `Modernizer` via a CDN and use a local copy of `foundation.min.js`. This way I have everything I need now and in the future in the single included file. It is not that big and way easier then going with the I'm only gonna load what I need when I need it route.

Also to make sure `Foundation` runs on your page you will want to include the following right before the closing  tag:

```
<script>
  $(document).foundation();
</script>
```

I hope this has cleared up any confusion, and feel free to PM me or post comments if you need any further help deploying `Foundation`. I have been using it for a while and it is my new favorite Framework.

Comment: Matt Green, thanks so much for this. I just wanted to follow up for two things. Am I correct to have placed both <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script> and
<script src="/js/foundation.min.js"></script> in my application.html.erb file with the $(document).foundation(); script tag at the bottom? Would I need to modify the script file to be javascript/foundtation etc. instead of js. Lastly, to modify the flash, can I now modify it using traditional jquery fadeout command in a javascript file within my javascripts directory? I appreciate your help. thx.

Comment: jquery.min.js + foundation.min.js + $(document).foundation(); script tag at the bottom is exactly right. As for the other question concerning flash I would open a new question for that as it is not Foundation specific and you will get alot more help with that outside the foundation tag as it is not as popular as the `JQuery` and `Javascript` tags.