# Foudation fires window.onload twice

Tags: javascript, zurb-foundation

I noticed that including Foundation on a page, window.onload event is fired twice

[Codeped example](https://codepen.io/ftendi/pen/eYzJMEP)

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/6.6.3/js/foundation.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      window.onload = function() {
        alert('onload');
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>gjgjhj</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Is this the correct behavior?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Congrats on your first question on Stack Overflow! Yes, this is expected. If you experiment it a little bit, you can see when you comment out the `foundation.min.js` import line like this:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/6.6.3/js/foundation.min.js"></script> -->
    <script>
      window.onload = function() {
        alert('onload');
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>gjgjhj</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

it will only load the page once. So the one who load your page the second time is the Foundation javascript. It will reload your page to load all the Foundation functionalities.

You can see what it does here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23316686/1537413

Comment: Thanks for your answer: Why Foundation trigger the event the second time? My website includes an external script that do something on window.onload, but because of Foudation loaded do this twice! :)

Comment: it needs to load all the Foundation functionalities by loading the page again

Comment: ok, but is there a way to solve the described problem above?

Comment: No. if you want to use Foundation, you will need to ignore this "problem". It is like the ticket price you need to pay when you want to ride a train. I myself don't see this as a problem. This is only the way how you'd use Foundation